# How can I get the doc ID of the file i just created in a google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Using a google script I create a new google doc with the line;

```
var doc = DocumentApp.create(name + "-" + new Date());
```

I need to get the file ID for that newly created doc.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the id with the `getId()` method.

```
var doc = DocumentApp.create(name + "-" + new Date());
var id = doc.getId();
```

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getid